# Sending a Dynamic Text to Voice Call without URL Reference

Tags: php, twilio

In the Twilio documentation, it states you can send a text to voice call statically like this:

```
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

$AccountSid = "";
$AuthToken = "";

$client = new Client($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

try {
    $call = $client->account->calls->create(
        "+15555551234",
        "+15555554321",
        array("url" => '/twilio/twilio.welcome.message.php')
    );
    echo "Started call: " . $call->sid;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I find that to be a little bit much for dynamically created messages. This is fine for static messages. What I want to do is something like this:

```
use Twilio\Twiml;

$response = new Twiml();
$response->say('Chapeau!', ['voice' => 'woman', 'language' => 'fr']);

$AccountSid = "";
$AuthToken = "";

$client = new Client($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

try {

    $call = $client->account->calls->create(
        "+phoneNumber",
        "+phoneNumber",
        array("response" => $response)
    );
    echo "Started call: " . $call->sid;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

It hints at being able to do this in the documentation, but I can't find it anywhere. I'd be really shocked if there wasn't an easier implementation than creating a php script, to call, and then delete to get this to work. But I've seen worse things in my life.

Comment: Would you be able to explain a bit more about what you are wanting to achieve because it's not clear to me the trouble you are having. Are you trying to send multiple messages at once to different numbers?

Comment: Yes Andy, that's what I'm trying to do. There's numerous was I could do it with the method they provide clearly. I just don't see why I need to make an extra file for this when I shouldn't have to.

Comment: Where in the documentation did you find the `response` parameter?

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to the the URL parameter. I've edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid there's no way to send TwiML to Twilio to be executed when a call is answered. You still need to send a URL that will [respond with TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) when the call is connected.

However, you can make that URL react dynamically. If you are just sending a message to be read out then you could send the message as a query parameter in the URL and then use that message when the webhook is called. For example:

```
$message = "Hello! This is a message!";
$call = $client->account->calls->create(
    "+15555551234",
    "+15555554321",
    array("url" => '/twilio/twilio.welcome.message.php?message='.urlencode($message))
);
```

Then, in your webhook:

```
<?php
  $message = $_REQUEST['message'];
  header("Content-type: text/xml");
  echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n";
?>
<Response>
  <Say><?php echo $message ?></Say>
</Response>
```

This way, you can dynamically create messages but only host one webhook endpoint.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Yeah, that does help, and I've thought of it already. But why make a file to do that when it could just easily accept a message as a parameter in create, or accept TwiML. Instead of creating a whole extra file. This must be a common and typical use case and I'm just curious why it isn't being addressed by the company.

Comment: To me, and this is just my opinion, I don't work on the API myself, this only works for the very simplest of examples. if you were to build your application this way and then found you wanted to do something slightly more complicated, you would have to rearchitect your application to have an endpoint that could receive webhooks. In this case we're trying to simplify the ways that you interact with Twilio to this one method.

Answer (score 0):

What about using Twiml bin? This way instead of pointing to your server, you'd have a twilio hosted URL that generates the twiml for you. It supports dynamic variables, looping etc.

see : https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/230878368

And then use dynamic variables like this :

```
<Say>Hello {{CustomerName}}</Say>
```